# Optaplanner: how to handle minimum number consecutive

Tags: optaplanner

Let's assume a variation on Nurse Rostering example in which instead of assigning a nurse to a shift on a day, the nurse is assigned to a **variable** number of timeblocks on that day (which consists of 24 timeblocks). eg: Nurse1 is assigned to timeblocks [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]. Let's call these consecutive assignments a ShiftPeriod. There is a hard minimum and maximum on these shiftperiods. However, optaplanner has difficulties finding a feasible solution.

When having hard consecutive constraints, is it better to model the planning entity as a startTimeBlock with a duration instead of my current way with assignment to a timeblock and a day and then imposing min/max consecutive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the meeting scheduling example on github master for 6.4.0.Beta1 (but the example will work perfectly with 6.3.0.Final too). Video and docs coming soon. That example uses the design pattern TimeGrains, which is what you're looking for I think.